# React object Interface without nesting

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Just started learning TypeScript and I'm not sure I'm doing Interfaces correctly.
If we have code that looks like:

```
export interface PersonInterface {
    name: string,
    age: number,
}
```

When we have a component that uses the interface do we have to send these arguments separately?

```
const PersonCmpnt: React.FC<PersonInterface> = ({name, age}) => {
    return (<Text>{name + " is " + age}</Text>)
}
```

I want to be able to send the data as an object:

```
const PersonCmpnt: React.FC<PersonInterface> = ({person}) => {
    return (<Text>{person.name + " is " + person.age}</Text>)
}
```

But then it complaints about the interface, so I had to wrap my interface like:

```
export interface PersonInterface {
    person: {
        name: string,
        age: number,
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing things?

Comment: `(person) => ...` instead of `({person}) => ...`. then you don't need to put person in the interface

Comment: You could also destructure  nested objects `({person: { age,  name }})`]

Comment: When you put wiggly brackets around, you're deconstructing the object

Comment: Thanks for the help :)